# Test Restful Web API using Postman

Tags: rest, postman

I have a simple Asp.Net Restful API that I want to test using Postman.

How do I enter path parameter values into place holders or variables in Postman?

[image: Restful URL in Postman]

So in the illustrated example I would want to make fruitTypeId=apple and numberOfItems=10 so my final URL would effectively be myurl.com/fruit/apple/10

I tried using Keys in Postman but that adds querystring parameters e.g. /?fruitTypeId=apple&numberOfItems=10. That is not what I need I'm not using querystrings, but rather Restful path values.

I don't want to change the URL path every time with new values. I'm looking for an easier UI to simple change the values of the path values in a textbox.

Comment: Have you tried using [Environments](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/environments)?

Comment: Thanks, will check it out.